# sed how to do "or"

Tags: regular-expression, ruby, rspec

I have the following two lines that work ok:

```
/\.to <\=/ s/<\=/be <\=/
/\.to_not <\=/ s/<\=/be <\=/
```

I would like to combine them and I tried:

```
/\.to( |_not )<\=/ s/<\=/be <\=/
```

but it doesn't match. What should I change?

I also tried `/\.to(\s|_not )<\=/ s/<\=/be <\=/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sed, you must escape the parentheses and `|`.

```
/\.to\( \|_not \)<\=/ s/<\=/be <\=/
```

Alternatively, in your example you could use `?` (also escaped):

```
/\.to\(_not\)\? <\=/ s/<\=/be <\=/
```

Comment: but you don't need to escape the `=`